# Laravel Bundle OneAuth compatibility with Sentry

Tags: laravel

My team and I(the business/idea guy) are developing a new Startup using the Laravel framework.  I'm not a tech guy but I want to learn as much as possible.

We began with installing and utilizing the Sentry Bundle, and then added the OneAuth bundle for the Facebook login; however, we continued to get errors.

Is OneAuth not compatible with Sentry?
Sentry is coming out with a socialplugin soon.  Should we just wait for that or how should we go about this?

Comment: Also, does anyone out there know how long we might have to wait for Sentry's social plugin?

Comment: Hi David, I installed Sentry and very quickly uninstalled it. It was horrible to work with in Laravel as it appeared to be very buggy. I switched to the Verify bundle that has worked seamlessly for me since the switch.

Answer (score 4):

OneAuth author here, the problem right now is Sentry is not using Laravel Auth Driver to authenticate the user which make it difficult for the integration to happen. The two way to tackle the limitation:

- Convert all Auth called in OneAuth to use Laravel\IoC, this would require Sentry to register IoC on their side.
- Sentry to add an adapter class (extends Laravel\Auth\Drivers\Driver)

Either ways, there some works need to be done on Sentry side, I'm open for solution if they are looking to use OneAuth as their social plugin.

Comment: IoC support added to OneAuth https://github.com/codenitive/laravel-oneauth/issues/9#issuecomment-7675050